# Working with multidimensional arrays in C# similar to Java

Tags: c#, java, arrays, porting, multidimensional-array

In Java we can do this:

```
bool[][] something = new bool[5][10];

// Then, we can do this, since indexes do not refer to null instances:
something [3][7] = true;
```

However, the same does not seem to compile in C#. Is there an equivalent way of doing this in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different:

```
bool[,] something = new bool[5,10];
// Then, we can do this, since indexes do not refer to null instances:
something [3,7] = true;
```

Or if you are using C# 3.0+, you can slightly simplify the declaration:

```
//Doesn't work for fields.
var something = new bool[5,10];
```

That is a multi-dimensional array. You can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) for more information.

Comment: might be easier on the eye with a `var` :)

Comment: @RussCam - Good point, but I was trying to keep it as close to the original code as possible. (It could also be a field for all I know, too).

Comment: I understand. I wonder if the OP knows about the keyword though?

Comment: @RussCam - I updated my answer to point out that `var` is an option.

Comment: @Russ Cam:um..for curiosity, why use `var` instead of real type?

Comment: @The Mask - purely less keystrokes and just as readable (in my opinion, of course)

Comment: Aren't C# jagged arrays more similar to Java multidimensional arrays?

Comment: A late note: in C# array.length gives you the size of the entire array, i.e. the product of all the dimensions. If you're porting over Java code, you probably want to use array.GetLength(0) to get the size of the first dimension, like you'd get from Java's array.length.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in your question will give you jagged arrays in C# (arrays of arrays).  These are different from multidimensional arrays (a single array with elements stored contiguously in memory, with multidimensional indexing).

I haven't done much work in Java, but a little research shows that the Java multidimensional array is analogous to the C# jagged array, not to the C# multidimensional array.

To declare and create the array of arrays, you would do this:

```
bool[][] something = new bool[5][];
```

This creates a five-element array whose elements are of type `bool[]`.  You'll need to create the elements separately (or acquire references to them from elsewhere, perhaps).  The five arrays need not have the same length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
    something[i] = new bool[GetLengthForElement(i)];
```

If you'd like them all to be 10 elements long, you could of course do this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
    something[i] = new bool[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

C#s, syntax is ever so slightly different. A very quick Google threw up [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).